# ¿Como connectarse a PostrGreSQL con un script python?

Tags: python, postgresql, excepciones

Quiero connectarme a una base de datos con un script Python pero tengo un problema hacerlo. Utiliso Psycopg pero me devuelve una excepción. Aqui esta el script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Pequeno script para connectarme a PostgreSQL con Pyscopg
#

import psycopg2

try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='eclipse' user='swiper' host='el host...'")

except:
        print "no estoy capaz connectarme"
```

Aqui esta le que me devlueve el terminal :

```
:~$ ./testPostreSQLPython.py 
I am unable to connect to the database
```

Tengo un url tambien... ¿Tal vez esta mejor para hacerlo ? Pero no me parece que puedo utilisarla con Psycopg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que estas intentando conectarte con una base de datos en un servidor remoto. Lo primero que deberias intentar es obtener algo más de información del error, prueba lo siguiente a ver si da alguna pista:

```
import traceback
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='eclipse' user='swiper' host='el host...'")

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e
    print e.pgcode
    print e.pgerror
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Por otro lado no deberias tener ningún problema para conectarte usando algo como:

```
import traceback
import psycopg2

params = {
  'database': 'nombre_db',
  'user': 'usuario',
  'password': 'contraseña',
  'host': '333.333.333.333',
  'port': '3333'
}

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e
    print e.pgcode
    print e.pgerror
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

A partir de  PostgreSQL 9.2 creo que si se acepta el uso de la URL.

Deberias comprobar que tienes autorización en la base de datos para acceder remotamente y si requiere o no SSL. Intenta conectarte en la terminal mediante mediante [psql](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html) para ver que no sea cosa de psycopg2:

```
psql --dbname=nombre_db --username=usario --password=contraseña --host=333.333.333.333 --port=3333
```